# Entity Framework 6 AttachAsModified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update EF from 4.x to 6.x (newest stable via nuget). After some work the application works for data retrieval but not for save.
For performance reasons we mostly used the "AttachAsModified" method from EF 4.x. In most cases we have the primary key, attach, modify the values we want to update and finally save.
EF 6.x does not have such a method so I tried the following:

```
var data = new CatalogNode
{
    CatalogNodeId = catalogNodeId,
    UpdatedOn = updatedOn,
    UpdatedBy = updatedBy,
 };

  CatalogNodes.Attach(data);
  var entry = Entry(data);
  entry.Property(e => e.UpdatedOn).IsModified = true;
  entry.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).IsModified = true;
```

Unfortunately EF throws a "DbEntityValidationException" that says that some additional properties are required and need to be set.

Edit:
Here is the generated CatalogNodes entity (setter includes call to OnPropertyChanged)

```
public partial class CatalogNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CatalogNode()
    {
        this.CatalogArticles = new HashSet<CatalogArticle>();
        this.LocalizedCatalogNodes = new HashSet<LocalizedCatalogNode>();
        this.CatalogNodeAttributeValues = new HashSet<CatalogNodeAttributeValue>();
        this.CatalogNodeMappings = new HashSet<CatalogNodeMapping>();
        this.TranslatedCatalogNodeNames = new HashSet<TranslatedCatalogNodeName>();
        this.CatalogNodeMediaAssets = new HashSet<CatalogNodeMediaAsset>();
    }

    private System.Guid _catalognodeid;
    public System.Guid CatalogNodeId  {get;set;}

    private string _catalognodeuid;
    public string CatalogNodeUid  {get;set;}

    private System.Guid _catalogid;
    public System.Guid CatalogId  {get;set;}

    private int _catalognodetype;
    public int CatalogNodeType  {get;set;}

    private Nullable<System.Guid> _parentid;
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ParentId  {get;set;}

    private Nullable<System.Guid> _linkid;
    public Nullable<System.Guid> LinkId  {get;set;}

    private int _sequence;
    public int Sequence  {get;set;}

    private Nullable<System.Guid> _attributegroupid;
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AttributeGroupId  {get;set;}

    private string _printcatalogtemplateuid;
    public string PrintCatalogTemplateUid  {get;set;}

    private bool _printcatalogpagebreak;
    public bool PrintCatalogPageBreak  {get;set;}

    private System.DateTime _createdon;
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn  {get;set;}

    private string _createdby;
    public string CreatedBy  {get;set;}

    private System.DateTime _updatedon;
    public System.DateTime UpdatedOn  {get;set;}

    private string _updatedby;
    public string UpdatedBy {get;set;}


    public virtual AttributeGroup AttributeGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CatalogArticle> CatalogArticles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocalizedCatalogNode> LocalizedCatalogNodes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CatalogNodeAttributeValue> CatalogNodeAttributeValues { get; set; }
    public virtual CatalogNode LinkedCatalogNode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CatalogNodeMapping> CatalogNodeMappings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TranslatedCatalogNodeName> TranslatedCatalogNodeNames { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CatalogNodeMediaAsset> CatalogNodeMediaAssets { get; set; }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The error messages I get are like:
 - *"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."*
 - *"The field \"CreatedBy\" is required."*

First question: Where can I see or set which fields are requiered? We currently use a database first approach.
Second question: Is there a workaround? The resulting update query does not update those additional properties. Of course I could set these additional properties to some random values and mark these properties as unchanged but there has to be a better way I hope.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post the EF mapping of your `CatalogNode` entity

Comment: Can you post EF mapping code (if any)? By default it would be in class  named CatalogNodeMap. Do you have any code in DbContext.OnModelCreating method? InterchangeFilePath is not part of your original CatalogNode class, are you sure that InterchangeFilePath  is property of CatalogNode class?

Comment: The errors were from another class, sorry for that. Now the error message is from the CreatedBy property of the CatlaogNode class. There is no EF mapping code, and no class like CatalogNodeMap.

Comment: Got it now. This property is marked as required in your edmx file. Solution is still the same - assign any value that passes the validation, empty string should be enough.

Comment: Yeah I think so. My other research says the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Where can I see or set which fields are required?

They are marked as not nullable in edmx file:
[image: EF designer with not nullable property]

Or they are marked with [Required] attribute:

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set;}
```

Or they are marked with IsRequired() call with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
```

Or they do now allow null value to be set:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

For example this allows null value:

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

2) Is there a workaround?

For partial updates the only workaround I know it is set some junk values on not modified properties just to pass validation. For example, let's update age property of person with id = 1:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Id = 1;
person.Name = ""; // not null string to pass validation
person.Age = 25;

var entry = context.Entry(person);
entry.Property(e => e.Age).IsModified = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Important: Attach() is not needed.

Comment: What to do with properties of type string? I obviously cant mark them as nullable because they are nullable by default. Despite that, entity framework says they are required.

Comment: @Andre check if those properties are marked with IsRequired() with Fluent API. It can be in your DbContext.OnModelCreating method. Or in configuration classes in Mapping folder (if EF Power Tools are used to generate classes).

Comment: They are not marked with IsRequired() or in the configuration class. In EF 4.x these properties were not marked as nullable too but it worked. I think old versions of entity framework just didn't do those validation.

Comment: @Andre are you sure that not required string property is causing the problem? Can you update your question with detailed error message?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the validation just dont work with partial updates. One solution is to override the ValidateEntity method or to disable validation by setting the ValidateOnSaveEnabled proeprty to false. Both are located in the db configuration class.